# Write a program which asks user to enter an amount of money and convert it into VND

Tags: java

```
package projectthuhai;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lecture5 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type an amount of money");
        String s= sc.next();
        
        if(s.charAt(0)=='$') {
            String s1= s.substring(1,s.length());
            double s2= Double.parseDouble(s1);
            double s3= s2*23500;
            System.out.println(s+" = "+ s3+" VND");
        } else if(s.substring(s.length()-4,s.length()).equals(" EUR")) {
            String s1= s.substring(0,s.length()-4);
            double s2= Double.parseDouble(s1);
            double s3=s2*27100;
            System.out.println(s+ " = "+ s3+ " VND");
        } else
            System.out.println("invalid input!!");
    }

}
```

[image]

Can anyone please tell me my mistakes? Sorry if my mistakes are silly, I'm just a new learner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are scanning a Euro, you are not scanning the complete String.
Scanner's **next()** can read the input only till the space, but you need to read the whole string (EUR part as well). So, we need to use **nextLine()** as it reads input including space between the words.

Below is the working code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lecture5
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type an amount of money");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        
        if (s.charAt(0)=='$')
        {
            String s1 = s.substring(1,s.length());
            double s2 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
            double s3 = s2*23500;
            System.out.println(s+" = "+ s3+" VND");
        }
        // else if (s.charAt(s.length()-1)=='R')
        else if (s.substring(s.length()-4,s.length()).equals(" EUR"))
        {
            String s1 = s.substring(0,s.length()-4);
            double s2 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
            double s3 = s2*27100;
            System.out.println(s+ " = "+ s3+ " VND");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("invalid input!!");
    }
}
```

We can also check for Euro as `else if (s.charAt(s.length()-1)=='R')`.
Feel free to ask any doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've already realized my mistakes